# How to monitor an ElasticSearch Cluster on the Elastic Cloud with Datadog?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, datadog, metricbeat

We have an elasticsearch cluster deployed to the Elastic Cloud and would like to send monitoring/health metrics to Datadog. What is the best way to do that?

It seems like our options are:

- Installing the datadog agent binary via the plugins upload
- Using metric beat -> logstash -> datadog_metrics output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can deploy the Datadog agent in a container / instance that you manage and the configure it according to [these instructions](https://docs.datadoghq.com/integrations/elastic/) to gather metrics from the remote ElasticSearch cluster that is hosted on Elastic Cloud. You need to create a `conf.yaml` file in the `elastic.d/` directory and provide the required information (Elasticsearch endpoint/URL, username, password, port, etc) for the agent to be able to connect to the cluster. You may find a sample configuration file [here](https://github.com/DataDog/integrations-core/blob/master/elastic/datadog_checks/elastic/data/conf.yaml.example).

Answer (score 0):

As George Tseres mentioned above, the way I had to get this working was to set up collection on a separate instance (through docker) and then to configure it to read the specific Elastic Cloud instances.

I ended up making this: https://github.com/crwang/datadog-elasticsearch, building that docker image, and then pushing it up to AWS ECR.

Then, I spun up a Fargate service / task to run the container.

I also set it to run locally with `docker-compose` as a test.